# Get checkbox is checked or not using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm running this code in Magento

```
<input type="checkbox" style="margin-left:24px" class="mydelete" name="checkAll" onclick='checkedAll(testCheck);' />
```

Comment: And I'm planning to get the property using class or name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added an id attribute to the element.

```
<input type="checkbox" style="margin-left:24px" class="mydelete" name="checkAll" id="checkAll"onclick='checkedAll();' />
```

Javascript

```
function checkedAll(){
    if (document.getElementById('checkAll').checked) {
        alert("checked");
    } else {
        alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AyoFaKI/1/edit)**

Comment: Thats why i mentioned it in my answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried this one before only but its not working in side Magento

Comment: yeah Ofcourse its working their but in my code its not working also for this i tried document.getElementById,document.getElementByName,document.getElementByTagName

Answer (score 2):

If you are flexible with using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can easily do something like -

```
$("input:checkbox").is(":checked")
```

which will return a boolean value based on whether that input box is checked or not.

Comment: The question does not have a jquery tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using below code.

```
var checkprop = document.getElementsByName("checkAll").checked;
alert(checkprop);
```

**EDIT**

```
function checkedAll()
{
    var theform = document.theform;
    if(theform.checkAll.checked )
    {
        alert("checkAll Checked");
    } else {
        alert("Nothing Selected");
    }
}
<form name="theform">
    <input type="checkbox" style="margin-left:24px" class="mydelete" name="checkAll" onclick='checkedAll();' />
</form>
```

Comment: @thanks for the reply But its giving "undefined" in alert message & i forgot to say i am doing this in magento

Comment: Ofcourse this won't work because `getElementsByName` returns a collection of elements.

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar Really boss its its displaying same "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the checkbox is checked:

```
<script>
function displayResult()
{
var x=document.getElementById("checkboxid");
alert(x.checked);
}
</script>
```

and in your body:

```
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Display value</button>
```